# Is there a clean way to reindex a pandas dataframe, where you don't know if the index is a multiindex or a normal index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe whose index might be a multiindex or may just be a normal index. This results from doing a groupby where there are one or more groups.

Regardless, I try to reindex with an index constructed from pd.MultiIndex.from_product. However this doesn't work.

```
a = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3], index=[1,2,3])
a.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1,2,3]]))

    0
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
```

The behavior I want is

```
a.reindex(pd.Index([1,2,3]))

    0
1   1
2   2
3   3
```

using code generic enough to support MultiIndexes.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the following helper function:

```py
import pandas as pd

def reindex(df_, multi_idx, *args, **kwargs):
    return df_.reindex(
        multi_idx
        if isinstance(df_.index, pd.MultiIndex)
        else multi_idx.get_level_values(0).unique(),
        *args,
        **kwargs
    )
```

Then:

```py
# Regular index
a = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3], index=[1, 2, 3])
a = reindex(a, pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]))

print(a)
# Output
   0
1  1
2  2
3  3
```

```py
# MultiIndex
b = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1], [5], [9], [1], [5], [9], [1], [5], [9]],
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]),
)
b = reindex(b, pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]))

print(b)
# Output
     0
1 1  1
  2  5
  3  9
2 1  1
  2  5
  3  9
3 1  1
  2  5
  3  9
```